# Upload Image using ajaxupload

Tags: php, jquery

I am using [Ajax Upload](http://code.google.com/p/aspnet-mvc-dynamic-file-upload-example/source/browse/trunk/MultiFileUpload/Scripts/ajaxupload.3.5.js?r=2) for file upload via ajax and php.
At js file i wrote following line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#uploadExists').length) {
        var btnUpload = $('#uploadExists');
        var u = new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
            action: '/upload',
            name: 'fname',
            onSubmit: function(file, ext){
                if (! (ext && /^(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$/.test(ext))) {
                        //Bad file                                                                                                                                                                         
                    return false;
                }
            },
            onComplete: function(file, response){
                if (! (/(\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg|\.gif)/.test(response))) {
                    //Bad file                                                                                                                                                                             
                    console.log(response);
                    return false;
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
```

At `/upload` url what should I do?
I am writing things in `PHP.`

Answer (score 1):

At /upload (for instance /upload/index.php) you receive the file via the $_POST variable. Try doing var_dump($_POST) to see what the filename is. Then you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php to move the file as you would like. This script will be sent 1 file at a time from the multi-file upload, so you handle the upload as if you were handling a single upload via a standard html form.